# Trying to refactor code to make it more dynamic

Tags: javascript, html

I have 6 `divs` each with `class="ray"`. I wrote some JS for my 6 `divs` but I want to make it more dynamic so that if I added 12 `divs` instead of 6, I wouldn't have to make a lot of edits to my code.

Here is the code I wrote, but I'm trying to refactor it and make it more dynamic: (My original code has 6 of everything, for this example, I'm only showing 2 of everything)

```
const rays = document.querySelectorAll(".ray");

let randAng1 = Math.random() * 90;
let randAng2 = Math.random() * 90;

let stopValue1 = Math.random() * 20;
let stopValue2 = Math.random() * 20;

let stop1 = Math.random() * stopValue1;
let stop2 = Math.random() * stopValue2;

let direction1 = "up";
let direction2 = "down";

setInterval(() => {
  rays[0].style.transform = "rotate(" + randAng1 + "deg)";
  rays[1].style.transform = "rotate(" + randAng2 + "deg)";

  if (randAng1 > 90 - stop1) direction1 = "down";
  if (randAng1 < 0 + stop1) direction1 = "up";
  if (direction1 === "up") {
    randAng1 += 0.1;
  } else {
    randAng1 -= 0.1;
  }

  if (randAng2 > 90 - stop2) direction2 = "down";
  if (randAng2 < 0 + stop2) direction2 = "up";
  if (direction2 === "up") {
    randAng2 += 0.2;
  } else {
    randAng2 -= 0.2;
  }
}, 50);
```

I was considering doing a `class Ray() {` somehow, but wasn't sure how to declare the `div` element as a class, if that's even possible.

Comment: You don't need to declare the `div` as a `class`, you can make it a class property, something like `const rays = [...document.querySelectorAll(".ray")].map(div => new Ray(div))`.

Comment: I'll try that! And then I can say something like:
`rays[0]` to target the first `.ray` element?
so `rays[0].angle' (assuming "this.angle" is a field)?

Comment: Yes, this way, every `Ray` instance will have an internal state, you'll need to define the constant values only once in the `Ray` class and each instance will have different variables that will change independently.

Comment: And can I still use `rays[0].style.transform = whatever`? Thank you for your help! :) I'm learning something new

Comment: No, that will be inside the class, you will just call a class function to do that, here is an example: https://jsbin.com/zuyegoyabi/edit?js  in this example, you'll just do `rays[n].update();`

Comment: Thank you for that code, I need to spend a bit of time looking through it and try to fully understand all of it.

Comment: The basic idea is that you can create a `Ray` using a `div` element, you can also specify the direction and pace or that `Ray`, something like `let ray = new Ray(divElement, "up", 0.1)`.

Comment: I finally got it! :) Now I just gotta modify. If you can create an answer with that in it, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I've added an answer, I haven't tested it, I'm not sure if it will work. Also, you seem to use a different increase/decrease pace (`0.1` and `0.2`) for different `div`s, I'm not sure how you decide this pace (or the direction), in my example is set based on the index of the `div`.

Comment: The pace was arbitrary. I just set the pace as `Math.random() * 0.2 + 0.1;`

Comment: I see, in that case, you can just replace `const pace = isEven ? 0.1 : 0.2;` with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare a `div` as a `class`, you can pass the `div` to a `class` constructor, here is an example:

```
class Ray {
  constructor(div, direction = 'up', pace = 0.1) {
    this.div = div;
    this.randAng = Math.random() * 90;
    this.stopValue = Math.random() * 20;
    this.stop1 = Math.random() * stopValue;
    this.direction1 = direction;
    this.pace = pace;
  }

  update() {
    this.div.style.transform = "rotate(" + this.randAng + "deg)";
    if (this.randAng > 90 - this.stop) this.direction = "down";
    if (this.randAng < this.stop) this.direction = "up";
    if (this.direction === "up") {
      this.randAng += this.pace;
    } else {
      this.randAng -= this.pace;
    } 
  }
}

const rays = [...document.querySelectorAll(".ray")].map((div, index) => {
  const isEven = index % 2 === 0;
  const direction = isEven ? "up" : "down";
  const pace = isEven ? 0.1 : 0.2;
  const pace = new Ray(div, direction, pace);
  return pace;
});

setInterval(() => {
  rays.forEach(ray => ray.update());
}, 50);
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps, this class will create dinamically a paragraph tag (with id='ray')nested to a div element, all inside the container element. The for loop at the bottom calls the class Ray for each element of yourArray (is just an example).

```js
class Ray {
  constructor() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    
    p.id = "ray";
    p.textContent = 'test';

    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(div);
    div.appendChild(p);
  }
}

const yourArray = [0, 1, 2, 3]; 
let createRays = [];
for (let i = 0; i < yourArray.length; i++) {
  createRays[i] = new Ray(yourArray[i]);
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I think I understand how this works. Now just need to apply this knowledge to my own project!